# How to merge two buttons into only one button

Tags: javascript, html

I want to merge these two buttons into one button:

First button code:

```
<input class='contact-form-button soracustomform-ok' type='button' value='Confirm Order'/>
<a class='simpleCart_checkout' href='javascript:;'><input class='contact-form-button contact-form-button-submit disabled' disabled='true' id='ContactForm1_contact-form-submit' type='button' value='Place Order'/></a>
```

Second button code:

```
<input class='contact-form-button soracustomform-ok' type='button' value='Confirm Order'/>
<a class='simpleCart_checkout' href='javascript:;'><input class='contact-form-button contact-form-button-submit disabled' disabled='true' id='ContactForm1_contact-form-submit' type='button' value='Place Order'/></a>
```

Check this demo template here: sorashop-soratemplates.blogspot.com/p/checkout.html

Try to place an order and you will see two buttons on the checkout page first button for confirmation and the second for place the order, I want to merge them in just one button, so when someone want to place an order he will just need to click on 1 button to confirm and place the order at the same time without click on confirm then place.

Thank you!

Comment: And what do you want the output to look like?

Comment: Both blocks of code appear to be identical.  What do you mean by "merge" here?

Comment: Please check this demo template here: https://sorashop-soratemplates.blogspot.com/p/checkout.html ,  try to place an order and you will see two buttons on the checkout page first button for confirmation and the second for place the order, I want to merge them in just one button, so when someone want to place an order he will just need to click on 1 button to confirm and place the order at the same time without click on confirm then place.

Comment: This sounds more like a question related to the HTML/CSS framework you're using, I think. Why don't you just make one button with the value "Confirm and place order"?

Comment: Because I'm not the one who made this blogger template, I'm editing to it to make it more useful and I need your help to make this thing works

Answer (score 0):

Is this just DOM a question? Because removing one of the buttons
means you need to refactor the backend to confirm your order "automatically"

[image]

Comment: Ah I see, so I need to buy the premium version with no-encrypted javascript codes to edit it